# How can I set browser caching on just .png files in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, browser-cache

Most of the content on my side isn't static but the images are (and there are a lot of images). I want to enable browser caching on .png files to make googles page speed test happier. Looking into it I see I can use something like `config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2419200"` in the production.rb file. But this caches everything including html. I just want .png files cached.

In htaccess files you just add the following to cache just .png files

```
`<filesMatch ".(png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"
</filesMatch>`
```

But for rails I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you talking about images served via the rails assets pipeline?